# problem in referencing resource folder in android project

Tags: android, resources, eclipse-adt

i am developing android project in eclipse ADT plugin.i download one open source project(k9 email client) from github.com. then i add android 2.2.jar file to referenced library folder of project but still i face problem with syntax like...

identity.setSignature(context.getString(R.string.default_signature)); identity.setDescription(context.getString(R.string.default_identity_description));

whenever i reference the resource folder it shows me error..so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to copy strings.xml from one of values-LANGUAGE to either res or values folder

Comment: hi fazo, but problem is not ony with the values folder but also with layout folder like.... super(context, R.layout.recipient_dropdown_item, null);

Comment: @saurabh patil: on github it looks ok - try reloading eclipse. and remember, that for every R.<something> you need to have <something> in res folder. R.layout.recipient_dropdown_item should not give you any error at all, that's why you have probably copied this wrong